# doctrine2 extra lazy fetching of association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a `Thread` entity which has a `OneToMany` association with a `Message` entity. I am fetching a thread with a DQL query, and I want to limit its amount of messages to 10. Therefore I am setting the fetch mode to `EXTRA_LAZY` as below.

```
class Thread
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Profile\Entity\Message", mappedBy="thread", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"timeSent" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $messages;
}
```

This allows me to use the `slice` method to issue a `LIMIT` SQL query to the database. All good so far. Because my messages are encrypted, I need to decrypt them in my service layer before handling the thread object off to the controller (and ultimately view). To accomplish this, I am doing the following in my service:

```
foreach ($thread->getMessages()->slice(0, 10) as $message) {
    // Decrypt message
}
```

The call to `slice` triggers an SQL query that fetches 10 messages. In my view, I am doing the following to render the thread's messages:

```
$this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('message');
echo $this->partialLoop('partial/thread/message.phtml', $thread->getMessages());
```

The problem is that this fetches the entire collection of messages from the database. If I call `slice` as in my service, the same SQL query with `LIMIT 10` is issued to the database, which is not desirable.

How can I process a limited collection of messages in my service layer without issuing another SQL query in my view? That is, to have doctrine create a single SQL query, not two. I could simply decrypt my messages in my view, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having a service layer in this case. I could surely fetch the messages "manually" and add them to the thread object, but if I could do it automatically through the association, then that would be much preferred.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about a slightly different approach than most have suggested:

**Slice**

In the `Thread` entity, have a dedicated method for returning slices of messages:

```
class Thread
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param  int      $offset
     * @param  int|null $length
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSliceOfMessages($offset, $length = null)
    {
        return $this->messages->slice($offset, $length);
    }
}
```

This would take care of easily retrieving a slice in the view, without the risk of fetching the entire collection.

**Decrypting message content**

Next you need the decrypted content of the messages.

I suggest you create a service that can handle encryption/decryption, and have the `Message` entity depend on it.

```
class Message
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var CryptService
     */
    protected $crypt;

    /**
     * @param CryptService $crypt
     */
    public function __construct(CryptService $crypt)
    {
        $this->crypt = $crypt;
    }
}
```

Now you have to create `Message` entities by passing a `CryptService` to it. You can manage that in the service that creates `Message` entities.

But this will only take care of `Message` entities that *you* instantiate, not the ones *Doctrine* instantiates. For this, you can use the `PostLoad` event.

Create an event-listener:

```
class SetCryptServiceOnMessageListener
{
    /**
     * @var CryptService
     */
    protected $crypt;

    /**
     * @param CryptService $crypt
     */
    public function __construct(CryptService $crypt)
    {
        $this->crypt = $crypt;
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $event
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof Message) {
            $message->setCryptService($this->crypt);
        }
    }
}
```

This event-listener will inject a `CryptService` into the `Message` entity whenever Doctrine loads one.

Register the event-listener in the bootstrap/configuration phase of your application:

```
$eventListener = new SetCryptServiceOnMessageListener($crypt);
$eventManager  = $entityManager->getEventManager();
$eventManager->addEventListener(array(Events::postLoad), $eventListener);
```

Add the setter to the `Message` entity:

```
class Message
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param CryptService $crypt
     */
    public function setCryptService(CryptService $crypt)
    {
        if ($this->crypt !== null) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('We already have a crypt service, you cannot swap it.');
        }

        $this->crypt = $crypt;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the setter safeguards against swapping out the `CryptService` (you only need to set it when none is present).

Now a `Message` entity will always have a `CryptService` as dependency, whether you or Doctrine instantiated it!

Finally we can use the `CryptService` to encrypt and decrypt the content:

```
class Message
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param string $content
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $this->crypt->encrypt($content);
    }     

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->crypt->decrypt($this->content);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

In the view you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($thread->getSliceOfMessages(0, 10) as $message) {
    echo $message->getContent();
}
```

As you can see this is dead simple!

Another pro is that the content can only exist in encrypted form in a `Message` entity. You can *never* accidentally store unencrypted content in the database.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty way of going about it. Generally speaking, I'm not too fond of the idea of having a service as a dependency in an entity, but it's a compromise I can live with. I will try to implement your solution ASAP, but it looks very promising. Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `slice` method's comment says:

> Calling this method will only return the selected slice and NOT change the elements contained in the collection slice is called on.

So calling `slice` has no effect on the global `PersistentCollection` returned by your `getMessages` method: I don't think what you try to achieve here is doable.

As a workaround, you could declare a `$availableMessages` attribute in your `Thread` class, said attribute not being mapped to Doctrine. It would look like:

```
class Thread {
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
    */
    protected $availableMessages;
    ...
    public function __construct() {
        ...
        $this->availableMessages = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...
    public function getAvailableMessages() {
        return $this->availableMessages;
    }
    public function addAvailableMessage($m) {
        $this->availableMessages->add($m);
    }
    ...
}
```

When you process your messages in your service, you could:

```
$messages = $thread->getMessages()->slice(0, 10);
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    //do your process...
    ...
    //add the unpacked message to the proper "placeholder"
    $thread->addAvailableMessage($message);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
echo $this->partialLoop(
    'partial/thread/message.phtml',
    $thread->getAvailableMessages()
);
```

There might be some differences in your implementation, like you might prefer having an ID-indexed array instead of an `ArrayCollection` for `$availableMessages`, and/or use a `set` instead of an `add` method, but you get the idea here...

Anyway, this logic allows you to control the amount of output messages from the service layer, without any implication of later-called layers, which is what you want from what I understood :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. While your solution would definitely work, it gave me an idea for a solution, which you can see in my own answer to this question. I made it work without adding a new property to my entity. Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should have a different class for decrypted message and push them separately into your view. Because `Message` is actually your entity-model and should be used for mapping data into your db but your purpose is quite different.

Because as I understood from your code you make smth. like:

```
$message->setText(decrypt($message->getText));
```

and after that you making even worse

```
$thread->setMessages(new ArrayCollection($thread->getMessages()->slice(0, 10)));
```

Imagine then, that after you made this changes, somewhere in the code `$em->flush()` happens.
You will loose every message except those 10, and they will be stored decrypted.

So you can push them as a separate array of decrypted messages (if you have only one thread on this view) or multi-dimensional array of messages with ThreadID  as first level.

Or you can implement the answer [Stock Overflaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269732/stock-overflaw) gave you.

It's up to you, but you certainly should change your approach.

And by my opinion the best solution would be an implementation of decryption as ViewHelper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You made some very good points, and I will strongly consider changing my approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if I figured it out. When calling `slice`, I get an array of entities. If I convert this array to an instance of `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` and call the `setMessages` method, it seems to work.

```
$messages = $thread->getMessages()->slice(0, 10);

foreach ($messages as $message) {
    // Decrypt message
}

$thread->setMessages(new ArrayCollection($messages));
```

Then, in my view, I can just call `$thread->getMessages()` as I normally would. This has the advantage that my view does not need to know that any decryption is happening or know about any other properties. The result is that only one SQL query is executed, which is the one "generated by" `slice` - exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Be careful using this: if you refresh (the EM's `refresh` method or the like) your `Thread` entity after the `setMessages` with decrypted messages and before your view is computed, then Doctrine would have reset the messages to what's in DB.
As a side note, I don't think you really need to wrap your `array` in an `ArrayCollection`, as I suppose your view just `foreach`es over the messages (which works on arrays as well as on iterable objects like `ArrayCollection`). Anyways, good thing you found the solution by yourself! :)

Comment: @Andy0708: As [Stock Overflaw](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1269732/stock-overflaw) helped you get to this answer, maybe award him the bounty?

Comment: Yay gimme the money! :p
In any case, I hope you saw and understood @JasperN.Brouwer 's solution which is really elegant and fully in the "ZF2 spirit" and, as highlighted by @Dropaq 's answer, both of our answers prevent you from flushing deciphered message content into your DB, which is another risk (along with the reset of your `Thread`'s messages I explained in my previous comment). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. You raised a good point with the risk of persisting decrypted messages. I will change my code when I find the time because I realize now that my workaround was not a very good one. Thanks - your help is appreciated!